# show the count of all the ordinary files from whole login

Tags: 14.04, command-line

can any body help me on this **Display the count of all the ordinary files from you whole login**

Comment: Homework or Test Question?

Comment: I am Learner it with my self i am php developer not a student so help to learn this @waltinator

Comment: What does it even mean? all the files in your home directory? all the files on the system that are owned by you? something else?

Comment: No I want to count all files in my whole login only files

Comment: @james  you mean all files opened by your username ?

Comment: Yes actually serg

Comment: **Note:** this question is very very basic. It is typically encouraged to show certain effort and what you've tried before asking. So, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: pwd | WC -l is not running it always show 1 @serg

Comment: `pwd` will return the "Present Working Directory" as a string. The pipe `|` symbol will pass that string to the next command which is `wc -l`, which will count the lines. As you passed one string to it, it will answer with "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lsof -u username` to filter all open files by username . It produces header line, so subtract 1 from the count of lines.

What you can do as well is this:

```
adminx@L455D:~$ lsof -u adminx | awk '{count++}END{print count-1}'
17999
adminx@L455D:~$ lsof -u adminx | wc -l
17998
adminx@L455D:~$ echo $(($(lsof -u adminx | wc -l)-1))
18008
```

A much finer solution would be

```
lsof -u adminx / | wc -l
```

That will limit count to type DIR and REG only